# How to handle `\indexentry{xyz@\texttt{xyz}|textit|hyperpage}{292}` with `xindy`?

Tags: indexing, xindy

I am novice to `xindy` and I'am trying to process with `xindy` an `idx` file which contains entries like this:

```
\indexentry{xyz@\texttt{xyz}|textnormal|hyperpage}{292}
```

Double formatting `|textnormal|hyperpage` here is the result of loading `hyperref` package over a source prevously edited with no `hyperref` in mind. Unfortunately, `texindy` ignores such entries. **How can one merge `|textnormal|hyperpage` to `\hyperpage{\textit{292}`?** I suppose that some instructions need to be added to `manual-i.xdy` module which is loaded as follows:

```
texindy -o all.ind -C utf8 -M manual-i.xdy  all.idx
```